# react-native-lottie package always throw error when updated macos operation system to Catalina 10.15.5

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

### Description

I am using `react-native-lottie` package in my project. But yesterday, I am updated my macos operation system to Catalina 10.15.5 version and always throw below error when run react-native run-ios command.

### Steps to Reproduce

1. Open the iTerm app.
2. runned react-native run-ios command in iTerm from react-native project directory.
   Expected behavior: `Running my react-native application in simulator or device.`

### Actual behavior:

```
CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/ios/LottieReactNative/ContainerView.swift
    cd /Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/Pods
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c /Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/ios/LottieReactNative/AnimationViewManagerModule.swift -primary-file /Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/ios/LottieReactNative/ContainerView.swift -emit-module-path /Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/build/sample/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/lottie-react-native.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ContainerView~partial.swiftmodule -emit-module-doc-path /Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/build/sample/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/lottie-react-native.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ContainerView~partial.swiftdoc -emit-module-source-info-path /Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/build/sample/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/lottie-react-native.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ContainerView~partial.swiftsourceinfo -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/build/sample/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/lottie-react-native.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ContainerView.dia -emit-dependencies-path /Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/build/sample/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/lottie-react-native.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ContainerView.d -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/build/sample/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/lottie-react-native.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ContainerView.swiftdeps -target x86_64-apple-ios9.0-simulator -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.5.sdk -I /Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/build/sample/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lottie-react-native -I /Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/build/sample/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lottie-ios -F /Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/build/sample/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lottie-react-native -enable-testing -g -import-underlying-module -module-cache-path /Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/build/sample/ModuleCache.noindex -swift-version 4.2 -enforce-exclusivity=checked -Onone -D DEBUG -D COCOAPODS -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -working-directory -Xcc /Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/Pods -enable-anonymous-context-mangled-names -Xcc -fmodule-map-file=/Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/build/sample/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lottie-ios/Lottie.modulemap -Xcc -fmodule-map-file=/Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/lottie_react_native/lottie-react-native.modulemap -Xcc -I/Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/build/sample/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/lottie-react-native.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/build/sample/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/lottie-react-native.build/lottie-react-native-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/build/sample/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/lottie-react-native.build/lottie-react-native-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/build/sample/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/lottie-react-native.build/lottie-react-native-all-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/build/sample/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/lottie-react-native.build/lottie-react-native-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/build/sample/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lottie-react-native/include -Xcc -I/Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/Pods/Headers/Private -Xcc -I/Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/lottie-react-native -Xcc -I/Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/Pods/Headers/Public -Xcc -I/Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/DoubleConversion -Xcc -I/Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core -Xcc -I/Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-DevSupport -Xcc -I/Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-RCTActionSheet -Xcc -I/Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-RCTAnimation -Xcc -I/Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-RCTBlob -Xcc -I/Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-RCTImage -Xcc -I/Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-RCTLinking -Xcc -I/Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-RCTNetwork -Xcc -I/Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-RCTSettings -Xcc -I/Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-RCTText -Xcc -I/Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-RCTVibration -Xcc -I/Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-RCTWebSocket -Xcc -I/Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-cxxreact -Xcc -I/Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-jsi -Xcc -I/Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-jsiexecutor -Xcc -I/Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-jsinspector -Xcc -I/Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/glog -Xcc -I/Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/build/sample/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/lottie-react-native.build/DerivedSources-normal/x86_64 -Xcc -I/Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/build/sample/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/lottie-react-native.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -Xcc -I/Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/build/sample/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/lottie-react-native.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DPOD_CONFIGURATION_DEBUG=1 -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -module-name lottie_react_native -o /Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/build/sample/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/lottie-react-native.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ContainerView.o -index-store-path /Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/build/sample/Index/DataStore -index-system-modules
/Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/ios/LottieReactNative/AnimationViewManagerModule.swift:5:8: error: module compiled with Swift 5.1.2 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.2.4 compiler: /Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/ios/build/sample/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lottie-ios/Lottie.swiftmodule/x86_64-apple-ios-simulator.swiftmodule

import Lottie
       ^


** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/ios/LottieReactNative/AnimationViewManagerModule.swift
        CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/user/Documents/React_Native/sample/node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/ios/LottieReactNative/ContainerView.swift
        CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
(3 failures)
```

### Versions

- npm: `6.13.4`
- macOS: `Catalina 10.15.5`
- react-native: `0.60.5`
- react-native-cli: `2.0.1`
- lottie-ios: `3.1.3`
- lottie-react-native: `3.3.2`